# Is stdin, stdout, stderr buffered or unbuffered in Lua?

Tags: lua, stdout, stdin

I can't really find much information out there that mentions this. Are these standard io descriptors setup to be buffered or unbuffered by default in Lua? Can I switch from one mode to the other if desired?

For instance, in python it provides something like `sys.stdin.detach` for making it unbuffered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [setvbuf](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file%3asetvbuf). It is an interface to the underlying C `setvbuf` function.

For example you can use it like this:

```
io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'    -- switch off buffering for stdout
```

AFAIK Lua relies on the underlying C runtime to hook into standard streams, therefore I think the usual guarantees for C standard streams apply.

Answer (score 4):

As this question also asks the **default** buffer-ness for standard streams. Since Lua uses C's  standard streams internally, the same rule applies:

Standard C requires:

1. Standard input and standard output are fully buffered, if and only
   if they do not refer to an interactive device.
2. Standard error is never fully buffered.

POSIX implies (but not requires):

1. Standard error is always unbuffered.
2. All other streams are line buffered if they refer to a terminal
   device; otherwise, they are fully buffered.

The same as C, one can use [`setvbuf`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-file%3asetvbuf) to change buffer status.